# REST API's issue

Tags: ios, iphone, rest, ipad, swift3

I am working on `REST API's` in `iOS application`.

I have tested `Server URL` and `Parameters` of `POST` method.

It is returning with

**Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand**

this error in response.

For the `GET` request `API` is working fine.
If anyone faced the same issue please let me know.

Thank you.

Please check my web service model

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default;
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
var urlString = String()
urlString.append(Constant.BASE_URL)
urlString.append(methodName)

let encodedUrl = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
let serverUrl: URL = URL(string: (encodedUrl?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed))!)!
var request : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: serverUrl, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 60.0)
var paramStr : String = String()
if requestDict.count > 0 {
    let keysArray = requestDict.keys
    for  key in keysArray {
        if paramStr.isEmpty{
            paramStr.append("\(key)=\(requestDict[key]! as! String)")
        }else{
            paramStr.append("&\(key)=\(requestDict[key]! as! String)")
        }
    }
}

let postData:Data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestDict)//paramStr.data(using: .utf8)!
let reqJSONStr = String(data: postData, encoding: .utf8)
let postLength = "\(postData.count)"

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
//request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
//request.httpBody = reqJSONStr?.data(using: .utf8)

request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestDict)



if  headerValue != nil{
    let allkeys = headerValue.keys
    for key in allkeys {
        request.setValue(headerValue[key] as! String?, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
    }
}

let postDataTask : URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:
{
    data, response, error in
    if data != nil && error == nil{
        let res = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        let dict = convertToDictionary(text: res!)
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            //print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    successBlock (response!,(dict)!)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (error?.localizedDescription) != nil
                {
                    errorBlock((error?.localizedDescription)! as String)
                }
                else
                {
                    errorBlock("")
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorBlock((error?.localizedDescription)! as String)
        }
    }
    else{
        if let httpResponse = error as? HTTPURLResponse {
            //print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
        errorBlock((error?.localizedDescription)! as String)
    }
})
postDataTask.resume()
```

Comment: please post your current request implementation

Comment: Please check I have updated my question

Comment: can you post the function declaration? also baseURL and methodName should be necessary for test, you can provide it?

Comment: sorry but it is confidential

Comment: ok! I understand, I will post an answer as I think I have your solution

Comment: Okk Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Your URL Encoding is the main issue here set it to application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your backend is expecting an form-urlencoded request, then you should convert your parameters dictionary in an string url encoded

**This is an example**

```
let parameters : [String:Any] = ["ajax":1,"test":"abuela"]

var queryItems : [URLQueryItem] = []
for key in parameters.keys {
    if let value = parameters[key] as? String {
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
    }else{
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: String(describing:parameters[key]!)))
    }
}

var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
```

then if you

```
print(urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery!)
```

you will get

> `test=abuela&ajax=1`

then with this you need to add in your `urlString`

```
urlString.append("&" + urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery!)
```

**FULL CODE**

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default;
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
var urlString = String()
urlString.append(Constant.BASE_URL)
urlString.append(methodName)

var queryItems : [URLQueryItem] = []
for key in parameters.keys {
    if let value = parameters[key] as? String {
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
    }else{
        queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: String(describing:parameters[key]!)))
    }
}

var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems

print(urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery!)
urlString.append("&" + urlComponents.percentEncodedQuery!)

let encodedUrl = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
let serverUrl: URL = URL(string: urlString)!
var request : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: serverUrl, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 60.0)


request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let postDataTask : URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:
{
    data, response, error in
    if data != nil && error == nil{
        let res = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        let dict = convertToDictionary(text: res!)
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            //print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    successBlock (response!,(dict)!)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (error?.localizedDescription) != nil
                {
                    errorBlock((error?.localizedDescription)! as String)
                }
                else
                {
                    errorBlock("")
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorBlock((error?.localizedDescription)! as String)
        }
    }
    else{
        if let httpResponse = error as? HTTPURLResponse {
            //print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
        errorBlock((error?.localizedDescription)! as String)
    }
})
postDataTask.resume()
```

## IF your backend is waiting `application/json` http body encoded

You are passing an JSON object in the httpBody but your contentType header is wrong instead of `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` should be `"application/json"`, I think your json convertion is wrong try using your requestDict directly and `JSONSerialization` will convert the dictionary in a valid JSON object that you can use in your `request.httpBody`

**replace**

```
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

**by**

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

**Use this to convert to JSON your requestDict parameters dictionary**

```
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestDict)
```

Comment: hey Tried this solution still facing the same issue. Is there anything do I need to change on the server side for this?

Comment: can you update your question with the current code? @PradumnaPatil

Comment: I need to know if your service is expecting an URLEncoding parameters or a json in the http body @PradumnaPatil, your current implementation is using both ways as I think

Comment: In postman when I am sending parameters in Form Data then it is working fine is it means Json OR URLEncoding parameters?

Comment: then is URLEncoding, i will update my answer @PradumnaPatil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165718/discussion-between-pradumna-patil-and-reinier-melian).

Comment: @PradumnaPatil check my updated answer and let me know